# How could declaring a large 2D array crash a program?

Tags: c++, c, window, windows-ce

Windows Embedded Compact 7.

Running 16KB application from USB drive.

In main I have function1() and function2();

Function1() runs and prints out some information just fine.

Then the program dies.

(Goes back to the command prompt (pocket cmd v 7.00).)

Function2 contains a declaration at the top. This is for a two dimension array of doubles, used in a calculation, **that is actually commented out at the time.**

```
function2()
{

    LARGE_INTEGER li;   
    double time[PRIORITY_LEVELS][ITERATIONS]; // 256 X 1000
    double difference[ITERATIONS - 1] = {0};
```

The part that makes no sense:
**I comment out the declaration for the 2d array (remove it) - the program will run the rest of the contents of function2() correctly.**

What is possibly the issue here or how would I even find out?

I have 8GB of RAM. That should be more than enough for a 256X1000 8 byte double, right?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're mistaking physical RAM for memory available to a process...

Comment: @simon-whitehead: that stinks, why can't the process use more, the embedded compact image is suppose to run really small right?

Comment: @P.S.: can you clarify what exactly is the language you are using ?

Comment: This is C or C++; the code is not valid C#.

Comment: @mhd-tahawi: c/c++.....

Comment: How many different duplicates of this could we find?

Comment: @jonathan-leffler: ?? it's from http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118050460.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're attempting to allocate about 2 megabytes of space on the stack, which blows it up. 1MB is the approximate usual size of the stack (which could actually be less on your specific platform, I don't know the specifics), so you don't want to allocate large arrays there. Instead you should heap allocate the array, i.e.:

```
double* time[PRIORITY_LEVELS];
for (int i = 0; i < PRIORITY_LEVELS; ++i)
{
    time[i] = new double[ITERATIONS];
}
```

This will only take 256 pointers worth of space on the stack, i.e. 1KB assuming a 32-bit process.

The fact that you have 8GB of RAM is irrelevant; only 2GB will be addressable by your process (assuming 32 bits), and you only have about 1MB of stack space per thread.

Comment: @P.S. This code is intended to replace your line `double time[PRIORITY_LEVELS][ITERATIONS];`. You'll also need to `delete[]` all the arrays you've allocated with `new[]` otherwise they will leak.

Comment: Or you could use -- `std::vector<std::vector<double>> time(PRIORITY_LEVELS, std::vector<double>(ITERATIONS));` -- and not worry about memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

you have 8GB of RAMS, but not all of those will go to your process
the matrix is too big to be allocated on the stack, try allocating on the heap instead.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: That may be the case for C#, but not for C or C++.

Comment: there is C, C++ and C# in your tags, if it is C or C++ it is not on the heap, or am I wrong here ?.

Comment: Didn't notice the multiple tags. Apologies, my comment applies to .NET